# Bounding box vs. xshift

Tags: tikz-pgf, bounding-box

The `xshift` in the following figure breaks the bounding box:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} % used only for testing with "framed"

\newcommand{\parlistrdeepseq}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [start chain=going below, 
     every on chain/.append style={join},
     every join/.style={->},
     framed]

     \node[on chain] { map f (28:28:28:28:[]) };
     \node(x1)[on chain] { f 28 : (map f (28:28:28:[])) };
     % \node(y1)[below=of \tikzchainprevious.south, xshift=-3cm] {|f 28|};
     { [start chain=t1 going below]
       \node(y1)[on chain, left=of x1, yshift=-1cm] {f 28};
       \node[on chain] {514229};
       \path (x1.south west) edge[->] (y1);
     }
     \node(x2)[on chain] {  y : f 28 : (map f (28:28:[])) };
     { [start chain=t2 going below, transform canvas={xshift=1cm}]
       \node(y2)[on chain, left=of x2, yshift=-1cm] {f 28};
       \node[on chain] {514229};
       \path (x2.south west) edge[->] (y2);
     }
     \node[on chain] {  y : y : y : y []};
   \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\parlistrdeepseq
\end{document}
```

The output with the wrong bounding box is:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the `xshift`, it's the `transform canvas` that causes this behaviour. As it says in the `pgfmanual`:

> when you use canvas transformations `pgf` loses track of positions of
>   nodes and of picture sizes since it does not take the effect of canvas
>   transformations into account when it computes coordinates of nodes

You should put the `xshift` into the options for the `y2` node instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} % used only for testing with "framed"

\newcommand{\parlistrdeepseq}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [start chain=going below, 
     every on chain/.append style={join},
     every join/.style={->},
     framed]

     \node[on chain] { map f (28:28:28:28:[]) };
     \node(x1)[on chain] { f 28 : (map f (28:28:28:[])) };
     % \node(y1)[below=of \tikzchainprevious.south, xshift=-3cm] {|f 28|};
     { [start chain=t1 going below]
       \node(y1)[on chain, left=of x1, yshift=-1cm] {f 28};
       \node[on chain] {514229};
       \path (x1.south west) edge[->] (y1);
     }
     \node(x2)[on chain] {  y : f 28 : (map f (28:28:[])) };
     { [start chain=t2 going below]
       \node(y2)[on chain, left=of x2, xshift=1cm, yshift=-1cm] {f 28};
       \node[on chain] {514229};
       \path (x2.south west) edge[->] (y2);
     }
     \node[on chain] {  y : y : y : y []};
   \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\parlistrdeepseq
\end{document}
```

Comment: But that doesn't translate the edge going out of `y:f 28:...`. The edge pointing to `y2` is supposed to start from the `f 28` part of `x2`.

But, with one additional change to the definition of the edge from `x2` to `y2`, it works! The new definition is:

`\path ($(x2.south west) + (1cm, 0)$) edge[->] (y2);`

(using the `calc` library)